# generalization and the Poincaré and Brouwer theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Theorem:
There exists a continuous vector field without singularities on the sphere $S^{n}$ , if only if , $n$ is odd.

I'm really stuck on how to prove this.

Comment: What is the question? What is $\mu$? How is this related to real analysis or limits (with or without L'Hospital)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are generally true.

If $\frac ab = -\frac 12$, then the right hand side is

$$-\left\lfloor-\frac ab\right\rfloor - 1 = -\left\lfloor\frac 12\right\rfloor - 1 = -0-1 = -1$$

For the first, as a counter example, consider $x = 0$. Then

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = 0 \ne -1$$

For the second, as a counter example, consider $x = -42$. Then

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = -42 \ne -1$$

Comment: applies for lateral limits ???????????